# Can a TeX engine be run without any format?

Tags: tex-core

It is my understanding that in all the major contemporary TeX distributions (TeX Live, MikTeX, MacTex), all the console-based commands for running a TeX engine (e.g. `tex`, `latex`, `pdftex`, `xetex`, `lualatex`, `context`, etc.) also load one of three formats: Plain TeX, LaTeX2e, or ConTeXt.

Does any of these distributions make it possible to run a TeX engine from the console without preloading any format whatsoever, not even Plain TeX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes: IniTeX. Historically, this was a separate program but today is accessed by passing the `-ini` switch

```
pdftex -ini
```

This is needed to actually build formats: only in IniTeX mode can one use `\dump` to create a format. (Engines other than LuaTeX can also only read `\patterns` in IniTeX mode.)

Comment: By the way, when I run `pdftex -ini`, will the engine recognize the extended primitives that pdftex provides on top of core TeX? If so, is there a way to run an engine that only recognizes core TeX, and that doesn't preload any format?

Comment: @EvanAad You also need the `-etex` switch to enable the extensions, though you get a somewhat odd selection without it (with pdfTeX you get the pdfTeX extensions but not the e-TeX ones, for example). Of course you are likely best using just `tex -ini` if you want exactly TeX90.

Comment: @EvanAad Note that you will get the same outcomes with TeX90 and pdfTeX even if you enable all of the extensions _but_ use a source that doesn't use them. (That's largely true for XeTeX too, whilst LuaTeX is explicitly not 100% back-compatible.) So if you are doing low-level experiments you don't really need to worry about explicitly excluding the extensions.